# Full Calendar with limitEvents. Reset or Refresh the view more button

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar with the new feature LimitEvents.

When I load the calendar with the domready, it works well. However I have a function to update the resources and to show new data in the calendar. The view-more buttons doesn't update, so I get multiple buttons.

Is there any way to refresh, reset the `limitEvents()`?

The idea is delete all the view-more buttons and load the data with a new limitEvents event.

I would like to use `limitEvents(2);` into `refreshCalendar();`

```
function refreshCalendar(){
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("removeEvents");
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("removeEventSource","./x1.xsp");
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("removeEventSource","./x2.xsp");
    var start_source1 = {
        type:'POST',
        url: './x1.xsp'
    };
    var start_source2 = {
        type:'POST',
        url: './x2.xsp'
    };
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', start_source1);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', start_source2);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        eventSources: [
            {
                url: './x1.xsp' // use the `url` property
            },
            {
                url: './x2.xsp' // use the `url` property
            },
        ],
    }).limitEvents(2);            
});
```

Comment: alway cache your jquery selectors var calendar=$("#calendar");

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that by changing view to basicDay and then back to month view, like so:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'basicDay');
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'month');
```

I don't believe there is a more efficient way